# Time constant of first order system

Tags: steady-state

I am new to this site, so please bear with me.
here is plot of the step response of first order system given 
[image]

Now, the question is to find time constant as well as DC gain so I can find it's transfer function.
here is my attempt, but I am not sure about finding the time constant.

[image]

I read somewhere that time constant for first order system is  t=5*tau where t is the time when system reaches its steady state value, so tau=3/5 ? 
is this correct?

Comment: time constant is simply tau. gain is OK.

Comment: how can I find Tau ?

Comment: I need to find Tau, so I can plug them into first order system equation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set \$ t = \tau \$ in your equation. This gives

$$ y(\tau) = Ku(\tau)(1-e^{- \frac {\tau}{\tau}}) = Ku (1 - e^{-1}) = Ku(1 - 0.368) = 0.632Ku $$

where K is the DC gain, u(t) is the input signal, t is time, \$ \tau \$ is the time constant and y(t) is the output.

The time constant can be found where the curve is 63% of the way to the steady state output.

Easy-to-remember points are \$ \tau \$ @ 63%, \$ 3 \tau \$ @ 95\% and \$ 5 \tau \$ @ 99\%.

Your calculation for \$ \tau = \frac {3}{5} \$ appears to be based on the time the curve reaches \$ 5 \tau \$ but that is very difficult to pinpoint on the gentle slope of the curve. In the graphical solution below it looks more like 0.5 s rather than 0.6 s. (\$ 3 \cdot 63\% = 1.89 \$.)

**Full answer**

[image]

\$ \tau \$ = 0.5.

Comment: Then inspect the graph. Find the point where y(t) = 0.632Ku, and draw a vertical line at that point. Where that vertical intersects the time axis, that is tau (assuming the step occurred at t=0, which it looks like it did in your graph).

Comment: See updates added.

Comment: so here is what I understand , y(tau)=0.613*3/2*2=1.89, I found value on the graph where t=0.5 seconds which is around 3/5=0.6 seconds I found already. then why my way was not correct?

Comment: I didn't know what '3' referred to in the '3/5'. I'll delete that line from my answer. As you can see, it's hard to see the 99% point on the graph but much easier to mark the 63% point. There's a difference of 20% in our answers which may be significant in an exam or in the real world.

Comment: Your way is not totally incorrect. Basically what they are saying is that after 5 taus have elapsed, the function is apprximately at its final value. But I don't like trying to estimate at what point it has reached its final value, because you can always zoom in more and see that it is not quite there yet. In general, you will get a better estimate of Tau using the 0.632 point. Or, you can just remember that after time tau, it will be about 2/3 of the way to its final value. That is what I usually do. 2/3 is close enough to 0.632 most of the time.

Comment: Also, if you can draw the tangent of the curve at t=0, then the point at which that tangent intercepts the maximum value (3 in this example) is at t=Tau. But that is also quite tricky to draw - but still worth knowing :)

Comment: Ha! I never saw that approach before.

Comment: There are a many ways to figure out time const , Thank you guys for your help